# SQL query inputs needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have UI where there is an search functionality. There are 2 parameters in search.

User can search of either of the two params to get the result (ie either of it can be null)

I am having difficulties in getting the to write the exact sql (SP) when one of the values is null.

For example as below:

```
declare @param1, @param2

create table #Ids
(
  Id bigint,
  Name varchar(10)
)

--Inserting multiple ids in my temp table
IF @param1 IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Ids (Id, Name)
        SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name 
        FROM MainIdTable I 
        WHERE (I.Name = @param1)
END

SELECT
    I.Name, S.ID, S.Value 
FROM
    SecondTable S 
JOIN
    #Ids I ON S.Id = P.Id
WHERE
    S.Date = '2012-01-06'
    AND s.tempId = ISNULL(@param2, p.tempId)
```

- If user enters `param1` value, the search works fine
- If the user enters both `param1` and `param2` values, then it also works fine

But if the user doesn't enter a `param1` value, but just enters a `param2` value, the search doesn't work.

I believe that's because my temp table is empty and when we make a join it returns nothing.

Any workaround to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Left join would give me all the rows whereas I want only rows that match

Answer (score 0):

```
Select I.Name, S.ID, S.Value from
  SecondTable S 
  LEFT JOIN #Ids I on S.Id = P.Id
  where S.Date = '2012-01-06'
  and s.tempId = isnull(@param2, p.tempId)
```

You should use a left join here.

Comment: Left join would give me all the rows whereas I want only rows that match.